# Objective -C: how can i get image path from my camera and use that image path in sqlite database?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I click an image in my camera application it will give me an image path in console.

That image path will be save in my sqlite database and that image will also be saved in a separate folder in my phone gallery.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to store (= copy) the image locally to your application data folder, do you want to persist a reference to the photo library, or both?

Answer (score 0):

using picker delegate. you can store the path in your db as well as write image to your folder from the path.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
  {
       NSURL* imageUrl = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
       selectedImage = [imageUrl path];
       NSLog(@"selectedImage: %@", selectedImage);
  }
```

Comment: This is my code for [ . m ] file -(IBAction)btnSaveEvent:(id)sender {
    NSString *strSaveDataBase = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"insert into addEventDetails values('@','@','@','@',)", ...........................];
    calendarEventDatabase * dbCalendar = [[calendarEventDatabase alloc]init];
    BOOL boolDB = [dbCalendar getAllUser:strSaveDataBase];
    if (boolDB) {
        NSLog(@"Data is Save:");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Data is Not Save");
    }
} 

What i have to write in String Format for to achieve image path in my db